# VSCode Creates an automatic breakpoint that I can't delete

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've created a basic node app following the steps described here - https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/nodejs

Every time I run/debug (hit F5), VSCode automatically breaks at line 2 of this auto created debug file. The weird part is there is no breakpoint set.

[image: The automatic breakpoint VS Code creates]

I can continue past this and everything runs a-okay after, but it's super annoying to stop here *every single* time

Any ideas on getting rid of this? I've poured through the settings and nothing obvious stands out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option in the launch.json file called "stopOnEntry" (You can access the file by hitting the Configure icon on the Debug panel). Set it to false and it should solve your problem.